# Writing a Wireshark dissector to count number of TCP flows

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have a very large tcpdump file that I split into 1 minute intervals. I am able to use tshark to extract TCP statistics for each of the 1 minute files using a loop code and save the results as a CSV file so I can perform further analysis in Excel. Now I want to be able to count the number of TCP flows in each 1 minute file for all the 1 minute files and save the data in a CSV file. A TCP flow here represents group of packets going from a specific source to a specific destination. Each flow has statistics such as source IP, dest IP, #pcakets from A->B, #bytes from A->B, #packets from B->A, #bytes from B->A, total packets, total bytes, etc. And I just want to count the number of TCP flows in each of the 1 minute files. From what I’ve read so far, it seems I need to create a dissector to do that. Can anyone give me pointers or code on how to get started? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tshark has a command to dump all of the necessary information: `tshark -qz conv,tcp -r FILE`. This writes one line per flow (plus a header and footer) so to count the flows just count the lines and subtract the header/footer.

Comment: Hello Evan, I have thousands of 1 minute pcap files. Going by your suggested method will be tedious to do. I have already used the tshark command you suggested but like you said, it's one line per flow so I put all the pcap files in one folder and wrote a code using the tshark command to extract the flows in each file and save to a CSV file. The problem is that I'm left with separate statistical data for each file in the CSV file which is a good thing. However, there are thousands of statistical data so if I have to count the TCP flows from each file, it would be too tedious to do.

Comment: Not sure what platform you are on, but on Mac and Linux you can pipe to `wc` to count the number of lines output automatically, so you can automate the whole thing. I imagine there must be something similar for windows, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into that. I'm currently using windows but I can try Linux. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Not a dissector, but a tap. See the Wireshark [README.tapping](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/README.tapping;hb=HEAD) document, and see the [TShark iousers tap](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=ui/cli/tap-iousers.c;h=d82fbb78b5a5aef8e18d2f99d3fcf512ce2f575c;hb=HEAD) for a, sadly, not at all simple example in C.

It's also possible to write taps in Lua; see, for example, the [Lua/Taps](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Taps) page in the Wireshark Wiki and the [Lua Support in Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/wsluarm.html) section of the Wireshark User's Manual.

The C structure passed to TCP taps for each packet is:

```
/* the tcp header structure, passed to tap listeners */
 typedef struct tcpheader {   
        guint32 th_seq;
        guint32 th_ack;   
        gboolean th_have_seglen;        /* TRUE if th_seglen is valid */
        guint32 th_seglen;
        guint32 th_win;   /* make it 32 bits so we can handle some scaling */
        guint16 th_sport;  
        guint16 th_dport;
        guint8  th_hlen;
        guint16 th_flags;
        guint32 th_stream; /* this stream index field is included to help differentiate when address/port pairs are reused */
        address ip_src;
        address ip_dst;

        /* This is the absolute maximum we could find in TCP options (RFC2018, section 3) */
        #define MAX_TCP_SACK_RANGES 4
        guint8  num_sack_ranges;
        guint32 sack_left_edge[MAX_TCP_SACK_RANGES];
        guint32 sack_right_edge[MAX_TCP_SACK_RANGES];
} tcp_info_t;
```

So, for C-language taps, the "data" argument to the tap listener's "packet" routine points to a structure of that sort.

For Lua taps, the "tapinfo" table passed as the third argument to the tap listener's "packet" routine is described as "a table of info based on the Listener's type, or nil.".  For a TCP tap, the entries in the table include all the fields in that structure except for `sack_left_edge` and `sack_right_edge`; the keys in the table are the structure member names.

The `th_stream` field identifies the connection; each time the TCP dissector finds a new connection, it assigns a new value.  As the comment indicates, "this stream index field is included to help differentiate when address/port pairs are reused", so that if a given connection is closed, and a later connection uses the same endpoints, the two connections have different `th_stream` values even though they have the same endpoints.

So you'd have a table using the `th_stream` value as a key.  The table would store the endpoints (addresses and ports) and counts of packets and bytes in each direction.  For each packet passed to the listener's "packet" routine, you'd look up the `th_stream` value in the table and, if you don't find it, you'd create a new entry, starting the counts off at zero, and use that new entry; otherwise, you'd use the entry you found.  You'd then figure out whether the packet was going from A to B or B to A, and increase the appropriate packet count and byte count.

You'd also keep track of the time stamp.  For the first packet, you'd store the time stamp for that packet.  For each packet, you'd look at the time stamp and, if it's one minute or more later than the stored time stamp, you'd:

- dump out the statistics from the table of connections;
- empty out the table of connections;
- store the new packet's time stamp, replacing the previous stored time stamp.

Comment: Thanks Guy Harris. I have looked at the tap documentation and examples you cited. I saw two examples that I think I can modify to suit my needs if I do some more research. I also noticed through my google search that there are not many lua/taps examples for different scenarios out there. Maybe I was just looking in the wrong places. Thanks for your suggestions. I'll get to work!

Comment: Hi Guy Harris, I'm not sure if this post is closed yet but I wanted to try anyway. I have a question. I read about Taps and I have simple functions for Listener.new, listener.packet, listener.draw and listener.reset. I'm trying to figure out how to write a function that will extract the statistics information I want using Taps and then count the flows. You said I don't need dissectors for the information I want to retrieve. I'm trying to understand how Taps can retrieve the flow counts I want without first retrieving the statistics. Can you help me with a code and some explanations? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have time to write the code for you, but I've updated the answer to give more information about how taps work in general and how TCP taps work in particular, and how you'd make that type of tap work.